# Убрать nbsp из строки

Tags: php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте. Достался тут проект на `CodeInteger`. Есть строка в БД (имя категории товара например). При выводе вместо пробела вставляется `&nbsp`. Что я уже только не пробовал: `str_replace`, `preg_replace` и т.д. Но она все равно остается! В БД обычный пробел. Подскажите пожалуйсте, откуда она может браться и как избавиться?

Это нужно исправить, чтоб был перенос на новую строку:
[скриншот](http://img.ni8.ru/137614504261_kiss_5kb.png)

UPDATE:
К строке на английском не добавляется. Там обычный пробел. Что-то с кодировкой

Answer (score 3):

Тоже долго искал ответ на этот вопрос, в моём случае помогла такая конструкция, может кому-нибудь пригодиться.

```
$text = htmlentities($text);
$text = str_replace("&nbsp;",'',$text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда мучаешься-мучаешься и как только спросишь, сам ответ находишь. Переписал ручками строки в БД и все стало как надо. MySql Workbench значит тоже &nbsp как пробел показывает.
Скорее всего при добавлении из админки стоит htmlspecialchars и уже в БД летят &nbsp вместо пробелов.

Comment: пользуйтесь консольным mysql, и все будет в порядке.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = html_entity_decode($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
```

Comment: @dimka3210, тоже пробовал. Не помогает(( Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

> При выводе вместо пробела вставляется &nbsp. Но она все равно остается! В БД обычный пробел.

Десятичный код неразрывного пробела 160, шестнадцатеричный 0xA0. Именно этот символ надо заменять.

А мнемоника `&nbsp;` появляется, скорее всего, уже при формировании разметки.

Answer (score -1):

Так короче:

```
str_replace(chr(160), ' ', html_entity_decode($string))
```